# Using Serial Port with Visual Studio 2010 Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I'm developing an application with Visual Studio 2010. I would like to send inputs and read through the serial port. I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open serial ports with `CreateFile`: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Though, if you're totally new to this, you should probably start here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx